# Bootstrap navbar alignment on right issue with no collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am having trouble with the alignment of the navs inside a bootstrap navbar.

created a minimal code in plunkr. 
Plunkr [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/4aX2vEzpO78i6fWpLoS4/)

thing i am having difficulties:

- I want to move the "Problem" nav to the extreme right.
- When I try to view in mobile or tablet version, the same problem nav goes down creating 2 lines.

How can i solve both of this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On the top “.navbar-header” add a `pull-left` class. This header doesn’t float for mobile by default. Adding pull-left will give the header room to the right to display your problem nav.
2. Once that “.navbar-header” has closed add in a new div, `<div class=“pull-right”></div>`. Your “.navbar-collapse” and “problem nav” are going to live here now.
3. Drop your “.navbar-collapse” and “problem nav” into it.
4. Update “.navbar-collapse” to `“pull-left”` and you should get the layout you are after.